# Snakes and ladders board - output does not print out

Tags: c

I'm trying to make the board of a snakes and ladders game by using C programming. I tried using coordinates to use as movements later, but for now I can't seem to get the board to be printed out, and I can't figure out why.

This is what the codes look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>

void displayboard(int ACROSS, int UPDOWN)
{

char x[50] = {};
char y[50] = {};

x[ACROSS] = 'x';
y[UPDOWN] = 'y';


printf("\n\t  ________ ________ ________ ________ ________ ________ ________ ________ ________ ________ ");
printf("\n\t | GO  TO |        |        |        |        |        |        |  GO TO |        |        |");
printf("\n\t | BOX 49 |        |        |        |        |        |        |  BOX 1 |        |  WIN!  |");
printf("\n\t |   %d   |   %d   |   %d   |   %d   |   %d   |   %d   |   %d   |   %d   |   %d   |   %d   |",41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50);
printf("\n\t |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |");
printf("\n\t |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |" ,x[40],y[40],x[41],y[41],x[42],y[42],x[43],y[43],x[44],y[44],x[45],y[45],x[46],y[46],x[47],y[47],x[48],y[48],x[49],y[49]);
printf("\n\t |________|________|________|________|________|________|________|________|________|________|");
printf("\n\t |   REV  |        |        |        | GO TO  |        |        |        |        |  PAUSE |");
printf("\n\t | 10STEP |        |        |        | BOX 11 |        |        |        |        | 2 TURNS|");
printf("\n\t |   %d   |   %d   |   %d   |   %d   |  %d    |   %d   |   %d   |  %d    |  %d    |   %d   |",40,39,38,37,36,35,34,33,32,31);
printf("\n\t |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |");
printf("\n\t |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |",x[39],y[39],x[38],y[38],x[37],y[37],x[36],y[36],x[35],y[35],
                x[34],y[34],x[33],y[33],x[32],y[32],x[31],y[31],x[30],y[30]);
printf("\n\t |________|________|________|________|________|________|________|________|________|________|");
printf("\n\t |        |  GO TO |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |");
printf("\n\t |        | BOX 33 |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |");
printf("\n\t |   %d   |   %d   |   %d   |   %d   |  %d    |   %d   |   %d   |   %d   |   %d   |   %d   |",21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30);
printf("\n\t |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |");
printf("\n\t |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |",x[20],y[20],x[21],y[21],x[22],y[22],x[23],y[23],x[24],y[24],
                x[25],y[25],x[26],y[26],x[27],y[27],x[28],y[28],x[29],y[29]);
printf("\n\t |________|________|________|________|________|________|________|________|________|________|");
printf("\n\t |        |        | GO TO  |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |");
printf("\n\t |        |        | BOX 40 |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |");
printf("\n\t |   %d   |   %d   |   %d   |   %d   |  %d    |   %d   |   %d   |   %d   |   %d   |   %d   |",20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11);
printf("\n\t |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |");
printf("\n\t |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |",x[19],y[19],x[18],y[18],x[17],y[17],x[16],y[16],x[15],y[15],
                x[14],y[14],x[13],y[13],x[12],y[12],x[11],y[11],x[10],y[10]);
printf("\n\t |________|________|________|________|________|________|________|________|________|________|");
printf("\n\t |        |  PAUSE |        |        |        |        |        |  REV   |        |        |");
printf("\n\t |        | 1 TURN |        |        |        |        |        | 3 STEP |        |        |");
printf("\n\t |  %2d    |   %2d   |   %2d   |   %2d   |   %2d   |   %2d   |   %2d   |   %2d   |   %2d   |   %2d   |",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
printf("\n\t |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |");
printf("\n\t |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |   %c %c    |",x[0],y[0],x[1],y[1],x[2],y[2],x[3],y[3],x[4],y[4],
                x[5],y[5],x[6],y[6],x[7],y[7],x[8],y[8],x[9],y[9]);
printf("\n\t |________|________|________|________|________|________|________|________|________|________|");
printf("\n");
}
```

I know it looks really messy, since I just recently started learning C, but it's kind of the best I can come up with for now. Although, if there are any better alternatives, I'd be open to read about it. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you see when you try to print the board? Error messages? Incorrect output?

Comment: Uh, well, nothing prints out at all. It's just blank then the program ends.

Comment: Empty initializer is invalid in C IIRC. You are trying to print a whole bunch of uninitialized values from array. Even if these are initialized to `0 you will get junk in output.

Comment: And apparently there is no `main` in this program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from a small formatting error at the bottom, it prints out just fine. 

[See here.](http://codepad.org/EKatQ2AH)

Note however that for writing such a kind of game, using standard C printing is not suitable as it doesn't allow you to move the cursor around freely or clear what you've printed before, so you cannot update what you already printed to screen. Not sure if Windows offers an easy way to do so but on most other systems it's a bit complicated and very system dependent, that's why people use libraries for that like [Ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses). It's not available for Windows but a library named [PDCurses](https://www.projectpluto.com/win32a.htm) is. It's code is public domain (you may use it in any way you like) and [can be found on GitHub](https://github.com/Bill-Gray/PDCurses).

### Update

Maybe I spoke too soon. Of course, if you know the exact screen size (number of lines and number of columns per line), you can always print the entire screen which will cause the entire screen to be refreshed. Check out this demonstration code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <time.h>

#if defined (__WIN32__)
#   include <windows.h>
#else
#   include <unistd.h>
#endif

#define TERM_WIDTH    80
#define TERM_HEIGHT   25
#define STAR_COUNT  1000

static const float STAR_SPEED = 1.5;
static const unsigned SPACE_DEPTH = 70;
static const unsigned FRAME_DURATION = 24;
static const char BANNER_TEXT[] = "This is awesome!!!";

struct Star {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

static unsigned gBannerPosition;
static struct Star gStars[STAR_COUNT];
static char gBanner[2 * TERM_WIDTH];
static char gScreen[TERM_HEIGHT][TERM_WIDTH];

static
void sleepForMS ( unsigned milliseconds ) {
#if defined (__WIN32__)
    Sleep(milliseconds);
#else
    usleep(milliseconds * 1000);
#endif
}

static
void clearScreen ( ) {
    memset(gScreen, ' ', sizeof(gScreen));
}

static
void printScreen ( ) {
    printf("%.*s", (int)sizeof(gScreen), (char *)gScreen);
    fflush(stdout);
}

static
void animateBanner ( ) {
    const int line = (TERM_HEIGHT / 2);
    memcpy(gScreen[line], &gBanner[gBannerPosition], sizeof(gScreen[line]));
    gBannerPosition--;
    if (gBannerPosition == 0) {
        gBannerPosition = sizeof(gScreen[12]);
    }
}

static
struct Star spawnNewStar ( bool randomZ )  {
    return (struct Star){
        .x = (float)random() / INT_MAX * 50 - 25,
        .y = (float)random() / INT_MAX * 50 - 25,
        .z = randomZ ?
                ((float)random() / INT_MAX * SPACE_DEPTH - 1) + 1
                : SPACE_DEPTH
    };
}

static
void animateStars ( ) {
    for (unsigned s = 0; s < STAR_COUNT; s++) {
        gStars[s].z -= STAR_SPEED;
        if (gStars[s].z <= 0) {
            gStars[s] = spawnNewStar(false);
        }
        float zFactor = 128.f / (gStars[s].z + FLT_MIN);
        int x = round(gStars[s].x * zFactor + (TERM_WIDTH / 2));
        int y = round(gStars[s].y * zFactor + (TERM_HEIGHT / 2));
        if (x >= 0 && x < TERM_WIDTH && y >= 0 && y < TERM_HEIGHT) {
            float starSize = (SPACE_DEPTH - gStars[s].z) / SPACE_DEPTH;
            char starSign = '#';
            if (starSize < 0.25) {
                starSign = '.';
            } else if (starSize < 0.5) {
                starSign = '+';
            } else if (starSize < 0.75) {
                starSign = '*';
            }
            gScreen[y][x] = starSign;
        }
    }
}

static
void initStars ( ) {
    srandom(time(NULL));
    for (unsigned s = 0; s < STAR_COUNT; s++) {
        gStars[s] = spawnNewStar(true);
    }
}

static
size_t minsize ( size_t a, size_t b ) { return a < b ? a : b; }

static
void initBanner ( ) {
    memset(gBanner, ' ', sizeof(gBanner));
    memcpy(gBanner, BANNER_TEXT,
        minsize(sizeof(BANNER_TEXT) - 1, TERM_WIDTH)
    );
    memcpy(&gBanner[TERM_WIDTH], BANNER_TEXT,
        minsize(sizeof(BANNER_TEXT) - 1, TERM_WIDTH)
    );
    gBannerPosition = TERM_WIDTH;
}

int main ( int argc, const char * const * const argv ) {
    initStars();
    initBanner();
    while (1) {
        clearScreen();
        animateStars();
        animateBanner();
        printScreen();
        sleepForMS(FRAME_DURATION);
    }
}
```

By default it expects your terminal to be 80x25 characters but just change the defines on top and you can make it fit to any terminal size. These values must be correct, otherwise it will not display correctly. Whether it looks good or horrible depends on how fast your terminal is able to refresh its content. You might be able to tweak results a bit by tweaking the `FRAME_DURATION` constant. Code builds on macOS using `clang -o demo demo.c` and on Linux using `gcc -lm -o demo demo.c`. I tried to make it compatible to Windows as well but didn't test it on Windows.